# How to exclude the results of an inner query in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to exclude the results of an inner query in SQL (I am currently working on Googles cloud platform), I have the following table:

```
date       | name 
-----------+------------
2019-09-10 | gas_300x10
2019-09-10 | gas_250x10
2019-09-10 | gas_3x3
2019-09-11 | gas_300x10
2019-09-11 | gas_250x10
2019-09-11 | gas_4x4
```

I am trying to exclude the values where the name is equal to **gas_300x10 and gas_250x10** for the date of **2019-09-10** only!

I want to keep the other values from that date and also want to keep where **gas_300x10 and gas_250x10** occur on other days for example on the day 2019-09-11.

I have the following query which **excludes the values for the date I do not want** - so I don't want those two values for 2019-09-10:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date = '2019-09-10' 
  AND (name = 'gas_300x10' OR name = 'gas_250x10')
```

This query would essentially return those values I do not want - how can I embed this as an inner query so that these results are excluded from the rest of the data?

I have tried using `EXCEPT` and `NOT IN` as a subquery but have not found any luck!

I think the code would work like this but I am unsure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
EXCEPT
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date = '2019-09-10' 
  AND (name = 'gas_300x10' OR name = 'gas_250x10')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combined expression:

```
select *
from mytable
where not (date = date '2019-09-10' and name in ('gas_300x10', 'gas_250x10'));
```

or

```
select *
from mytable
where date <> date '2019-09-10' or name not in ('gas_300x10', 'gas_250x10');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `NOT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE NOT (date = '2019-09-10' AND
           name IN ('gas_300x10', 'gas_250x10') 
          );
```

Note the use of `IN` to simplify the logic.

Alternatively, you can write this as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date <> '2019-09-10' OR
      name NOT IN ('gas_300x10', 'gas_250x10');
```

Both of these assume that `date` and `name` are not `NULL`.  The logic can be tweaked to handle this pretty easily, if that is possible.

I would NOT recommend using `EXCEPT`.  First, it removes duplicates, so it does not do exactly the same logic.  Second, it is doing much more work than necessary, matching the results of two subqueries rather than just filtering one table.

Comment: We gave the same answer at the same time and you put more effort into your answer than I. Strange that it's my answer that got accepted and upvoted. So here's at least +1 from me :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . My answer was about half a minute before yours, but there are no hard feelings as long as the accepted answer is correct.  I figure I "win" and "lose" the timing battle about equally.